# How do I make a div stick to the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains three SVG files that are layered on top of each other and supposed to be located on the center of the page. When the user scrolls down the page I want the SVG files to stick to the top and remain there.

As you can see in the CSS I have tried using `position: sticky;` and `top:0;` However I believe this is causing a "BUG" since the SVG files are layered using `position: relative;`. The graphic is now uncentered and it does not remain stuck to the top of the page on scroll. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sticky-Graphic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="one">
        <div class="graphic">
            <div class="child">
                <img src="SVG/triangle.svg" class="triangle" width="150px" />
                <img src="SVG/circle.svg" class="circle" width="150px" />
                <img src="SVG/rectangle.svg" class="rectangle" width="150px" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="two">
    </section>

    <section class="three">
    </section>
</body>

</html>type here
```

CSS

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.graphic {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;

}
.triangle, .circle, .rectangle {
  position: absolute; 
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background: rgb(72, 72, 171);
}

.two {
  background: pink;
}

.three {
  background: orange;
}
```

Comment: child is within graphic so it'll be positioned in relation to that, but it seems you want it positioned in relation to the viewport - is that correct?

Comment: try to use: **position: fixed;**

Comment: @A Haworth that is correct.

Comment: @Han Han thanks for your input. I just tried using position:fixed on the child class and the graphic sticks to the top. However the graphic is fixed to the top from the start, I need the graphic to start in the middle of the page and when the user scrolls it becomes stuck to the top.

Comment: Is it just `div.child` which needs to stick, or all of `section.one`?

Comment: @BrettDonald just div.child needs to stick.

Comment: @Jen One of the solution(at least not bad) is to use iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticky items are only sticky within their **parent** element. So if you want a sticky element to be visible throughout the entire document, it needs to be at the top level — a child of the body element.

This snippet demonstrates the idea. Note that the images/graphics are children of the body element, they are not wrapped in any sections or divs. I have used raster images rather than SVG graphics, but it will work the same with SVGs.

```css
:root {
  --image-size: min(20vw, 150px);
  --image-padding: calc((100vh - var(--image-size)) / 2);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: indigo;
  padding-top: var(--image-padding);
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  border: 2px solid white;
  width: var(--image-size);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
section {
  padding: 1px 0;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100vh;
}
.s1 {
  margin-top: var(--image-padding);
  background: cyan;
}
.s2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/136/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/137/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/139/200">
<section class="s1"></section>
<section class="s2"></section>
```

Comment: Your code worked! I just have to configure it so that the images or SVGs are stacked on top of each other. What does .s class refer to I don't see it in the HTML?

Comment: Ah, that .s class was left over from my experimentation. I have removed it.